# Multiplicative Functions Proof

Tags: proof-writing, multiplicative-function

I don't know if this question was asked before, but I could not find it on this forum: a function $f(n)$ is multiplicative if $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$, where m and n are coprime and positive. If $d(n)$ is the number of positive divisors of n, how can I prove $d(n)$ is multiplicative? Thanks.

Comment: Write $m = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_j^{a_j}$ and $n = q_1^{b_1}q_2^{b_2}\cdots q_k^{b_k}$.  Given that $m$ and $n$ are coprime, what would $mn$ look like?  ETA: Wait, are you sure that isn't $f(mn) = f(m) + f(n)$?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Math SX! 
Note that if two numbers are coprime, they do not have common divisors (except for $1$), therefore every combination $pq$ (where $p$ is divisor of $m$ and $q$ is a divisor of $n$) is a divisor of $mn$. Using this, the result will follow (I hope you can see it).

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function The OP's definition is standard in number theory

Comment: In number theory - yes; in general - no. However, if this causes confusion, I can simply delete it.